# Как передать большой файл на скачивание браузеру?

Tags: javascript, rest, download

Задача такая - передать файл на скачивание в браузер так же, как это работает при нажатии на **< a href="..." download="...">...< /a>**, но с помощью JS (axios, или XMLHttpRequests, или как угодно еще, но не через создание ссылки).

Код по типу такого не подходит, потому что он создает ссылку и запрашивает место для сохранения у пользователя только после того, как весь файл будет скачан.

```js
      
   axios.get(...)
   .then((response) => {
        const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(
          new Blob([response.data])
        )
        const link = document.createElement('a')
        link.href = downloadUrl
        link.setAttribute('download', 'name')
        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()
        link.remove()
      })
```

То есть, выбор места для сохранения файла должен быть ДО начала скачивания, и сам процесс должен идти независимо от страницы, с помощью браузерной очереди на скачку, с использованием стандартных функций докачки, прерывания.

Использовать тег < a> не могу, потому что нужно использовать токен авторизации, а с тегом это возможно только при использовании serviceWorker, насколько я понял, и хотелось бы этого избежать.

Comment: Зачем вам тут axios вообще? Что мешает просто поместить ссылку на файл внутрь <a> и не мудрить вот это вот всё?

Comment: @andreymal я писал в конце - мне нужно использовать JWT токен, файл находится в закрытой области. А добавить токен к <a> - тоже не такая простая задача, единственный вариант который я обнаружил - через использование service worker. Я надеялся, что может есть более простой и изящный способ.

Comment: Непонятно, что мешает добавить токен просто прямо в ссылку, все сайты делают именно так

Comment: @andreymal это возможный вариант, согласен. Он требует некоторой доработки серверной части, но в целом да, это вариант. Спасибо, самому почему-то в голову не пришло так сделать.